# Publish Issue VB.Net "The target GatherAllFilesToPublish does not exist?"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2017, publish

1. In case you face this ("The target GatherAllFilesToPublish does not 
   exist?") error when publishing a project which was built in an
   earlier version of Visual studio then please follow the below steps.

   - Right click the project and Unload project.
   - Right click the project Edit Projectname.vbproj file.
   - Find the below lines and comment it.
   - 
   - Add the below lines above the other two lines. Change the version number according to your new visual studio in my case it is VS 2017 
     hence I have marked 15.0

     1. 15.0    
               $(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)
     2. Save and Reload project and publish.

Answer (score 0):

Is this your current problem?
It looks more like you are providing a solution.
This error occurs when a project created with an older version of VS is loaded into a newer version.

As a side note, if your project created from `VS 2010` then you have `version 10.0`.if your project created from `VS 2013` then you have `version 12.0`.if your project created from `VS 2015` then you have `version 13.0`. If your new version is `vs 2017` then change the value to `15.0`.